# How-to send logs from Cloudflare worker to Google Stackdriver logging without Google SDK/libraries

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, stackdriver

We are trying to understand if there is a straightforward way to ship logs from a Cloudflare worker which would send an HTTP request to Stackdriver with a pre-created token such that we do not need to use the Google sdk/client-library as that does not seem to be supported in the Cloudflare worker nodejs environment i.e.

Is it possible to make a basic HTTP request to the SD logging service to write a log entry?

If so, how is it done? Can we do it with just an API key? Does it require any dependencies?

Any link to existing documentation is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: 1/2) Anything that the Google SDKs can do, you can do as well. It just depends on how much of the SDK you want to rewrite yourself. The good thing is that Google publishes the source code of their SDKs. However, before I would try to write detailed low-level code, I would understand how to interface with the services using the SDKs. Then once you have that knowledge, it will be an order of magnitude easier to rewrite the low-level code.

Comment: 2/2) Yes, there is a Cloud Logging REST API that is easy to work with once you understand how logs are created, written, and stored in Cloud Logging. No, you cannot use an API Key. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest